# Relation between a set's diameter and its measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a compact metric space, and $\mu$ be a finite positive Borel measure on $X$. Suppose that $\mu(\{x\})=0$ for every $x \in X$. Prove that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that, if $E$ is any Borel subset of $X$ having diameter less $\operatorname{than} \delta$, then $\mu(E)<\varepsilon$. I think that if $\mu(\{x\})>0$, then no matter how small the diameter is, $\mu(E)>0$, where $E$ is open and contains $x$. Is this the right direction to prove it? If so, is it enough for me to say this is true for $E$ being open without taking $E$ to be other kinds of Borel sets like closed sets or countable union/intersection of open/closed sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to prove that the measure of $\delta$-balls vanish uniformly at $\delta\to 0$. This then proves the statement, as any set of diameter smaller than $\delta$ is a subset of a ball of radius $\delta$ (that ball is by so much larger that any point of the set can be chosen as middle point. You *could* go smaller, but does it matter?). Your approach is kind of the other direction, as you’d prove that if singletons have positive mass the wanted property is wrong.

For a fixed center this is clear, for as measures are continuous from above for sets of finte measure you have $\lim_{\delta\to0}\mu(B_\delta(x_0)) = \mu(\{x_0\})$.

But how do we do this uniformly (so that $\delta$ does not depend on $x_0$)? Consider a particular $\delta$. If $x_n$ is a sequence of middlepoints that converges towards some $x$ (note $X$ is compact) so that $\mu(B_\delta(x_n))$ converges towards the supremum, then $\mu(B_{\delta+\rho}(x))\geq \sup_y\mu(B_\delta(y))$ for any $\rho>0$, so in fact $B_\delta(x)$ is of maximal measure.

Now take $\delta_n = 1/n$ and obtain such points $x_{\delta_n}=x_n$ that $\mu(B_{\delta_n}(x_n))=\max_y\mu(B_{\delta_n}(y))$. The set of these $x_n$ is at most countable, so we have again
$$ \lim_{\delta\to0} \mu\left(\bigcup_n B_\delta(x_n)\right) = \mu(\{x_n:n\in\mathbb N\}) = 0$$

Thus we get: For any $\epsilon$ there is some $\delta_n$ so that
$$ \mu\left(\bigcup_n B_{\delta_n}(x_n)\right) < \epsilon$$
But then for all $y\in X$ we have
$$\mu(B_{\delta_n}(y))\leq \mu(B_{\delta_n}(x_n)) \leq \mu\left(\bigcup_n B_{\delta_n}(x_n)\right) < \epsilon$$

EDIT: In fact we do not need compactness: If $x_n$ is a sequence so that $\mu(B_\delta(x_n))$ converges to the supremum, then we can find a point $x$ within that sequence so that for some (arbitrary) $\rho>0$ we have for all $y$ that $\mu(B_\delta(y))\leq \mu(B_\delta(x))+\rho$.

So then find such points $x_{\delta_n}=x_n$ that this condition holds with $\rho_n=1/n$. Then we can proceed the same way. We then take a $\delta_n$ so that
$$ \mu\left(\bigcup_n B_{\delta_n}(x_n)\right) < \epsilon/2$$
and that $1/n<\epsilon/2$. Then for any $y$ we get
$$ \mu(B_{\delta_n}(y)) \leq \mu(B_{\delta_n}(x_n))+1/n<\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2 = \epsilon$$

Also in fact we do not need that $\mu$ is finite, but it suffices to have local finiteness and some sort of robustness to translation.